# Merging two objects containing properties into one object

Tags: c#, .net

If I have two objects, `foo` and `bar`, delared using object initializer syntax...

```
object foo = new { one = "1", two = "2" };

object bar = new { three = "3", four = "4" };
```

Is it possible to combine these into a single object, which would look like this...

```
object foo = new { one = "1", two = "2", three = "3", four = "4" };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to be able to do this given any two arbitrary objects, rather than just doing foo = new { one = foo.one, three = bar.three }

Comment: (My vote to close as a duplicate was a mistake - I hadn't read the question properly.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do this. You've got two separate types at compile-time, but you'd need a third type at execution time, to contain the union of properties.

I mean, you *could* create a new assembly with the relevant new type in... but then you wouldn't be able to reference it "normally" from your code anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it's not convenient to do what you describe but if you just want to do some processing on the combined properties:

```
Dictionary<string, object> GetCombinedProperties(object o1, object o2) {
    var combinedProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in o1.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        combinedProperties.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(o1, null));
    foreach (var propertyInfo in o2.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        combinedProperties.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(o2, null));
    return combinedProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no naming conflicts, its possible using reflection to read the properties of the objects and merge it into a single type, but you'd not be able to access this type directly in your code without performing reflection on it as well.

In 4.0, with the intruduction of the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736(VS.100).aspx) keyword, it would be possible to reference the dynamic type in code considerably easier. It doesn't make it a better solution, mind.